# Postgres: Insert rule "RETURNING list has too few entries"

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, rules, sql-returning

Using Postgres 9.6 I have 2 table, a view that joins them and a rule that inserts into both tables when you try and insert into the view.

It works fine as long as the calling code it does not use the RETURNING clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE insert_my_view
AS ON INSERT TO my_view DO INSTEAD
(
  INSERT INTO tableA(tableA_id, name) VALUES (NEW.tableA_id, NEW.name) RETURNING *, NEW.some_other (or maybe tableB.some_other);
  INSERT INTO tableB(tableA_id, some_other) VALUES (NEW.tableA_id, NEW.some_other);
);
```

Is there a way to maybe make each insert return it's data and then I join the results for the overall returning statement?

Comment: To make views updateable using `instead of` triggers is the recommended approach.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP, I searched and searched and couldn't find the stackoverflow answer. Defo a duplicate question then

Comment: @DanielWorthington-Bodart Funnily enough, I found it through the "Related" links on the right-hand-side, but I'm not sure how the magic juice for those works. :)